# how to render home and header files together while routing using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-router-dom

I am trying to make an ecommerce web app using React. I have made the home page, now while routing. I am unable to render home and header files together. I have nested the home route under the header route. I have set the path for the header to be the default (path = '/') and I have set the home to be the index element.

This is my code now. When I run this only the header gets rendered.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Header from './Header'
import Home from './Home'
import './App.css'

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="app">
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Header />}>
            <Route index element={<Home />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to render a layout route to share some common UI elements/components, then the layout route component necessarily should render an `Outlet` component for the nested routes to be able to render out their `element` content.

Either of the following should work:

1. Update `Header` to render an `Outlet` component.

   ```
   import {
     ....
     Outlet,
   } from 'react-router-dom';

   const Header = () => {
     ...

     return (
       <>
         {/* Header UI */}
         <Outlet />
       </>
     );
   };
   ```
2. Create a new layout route component that renders `Header` and an `Outlet`.

   ```
   import {
     BrowserRouter as Router,
     Routes,
     Route,
     Outlet
   } from "react-router-dom";
   import Header from './Header';
   import Home from './Home';
   import './App.css';

   const AppLayout = () => (
     <>
       <Header />
       <Outlet />
     </>
   );

   function App() {
     return (
       <Router>
         <div className="app">
           <Routes>
             <Route path='/' element={<AppLayout />}>
               <Route index element={<Home />} />
             </Route>
           </Routes>
         </div>
       </Router>
     );
   }
   ```

For more information:

- [Layout Routes](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#layout-routes)
- [Outlets](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#outlets)